# Why string with dictionary replacement behaves abnormally?

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary in my application as below:

```
Dictionary<char, char> securityDictionary 
    = new Dictionary<char, char>
      {
          {'A', 'Q'}, {'B', 'W'}, {'C', 'E'}, {'D', 'R'}, {'E', 'T'}, 
          {'F', 'Y'}, {'G', 'U'}, {'H', 'I'}, {'I', 'O'}, {'J', 'P'}, 
          {'K', '1'}, {'L', 'A'}, {'M', '2'}, {'N', '3'}, {'O', 'S'}, 
          {'P', '4'}, {'Q', 'D'}, {'R', 'F'}, {'S', '5'}, {'T', 'G'}, 
          {'U', 'Z'}, {'V', 'X'}, {'W', '6'}, {'X', 'C'}, {'Y', '7'}, 
          {'Z', '8'}, {'0', 'V'}, {'1', '9'}, {'2', 'B'}, {'3', '0'}, 
          {'4', 'N'}, {'5', 'M'}, {'6', 'H'}, {'7', 'J'}, {'8', 'K'}, 
          {'9', 'L'}
      };
```

Now, I pass a string to this dictionary as follows:

```
string KeyFromClient = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVB";

Console.WriteLine(KeyFromClient);

foreach (KeyValuePair<char, char> c in securityDictionary.ToList())
{
    KeyFromClient = KeyFromClient.Replace(c.Key, c.Value);
}

Console.WriteLine(KeyFromClient);
```

Now here is my Output:

```
QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVB
DHGFGJKMMNDMFJKMNLAKCGCH
```

But I think the output should like shown below, because I am just telling my program to replace each character in string by looking into dictionary:

```
QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVB
D6TFG7ZOS4Q5RYUIP1A8CE0W
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are replacing values that you've already replaced. For example, you swap `A` with `B` and then in the next iteration your replace `B` with something else. A better approach would be to iterate through your string and build a new string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You're replacing some characters more than once.**

Consider the last character. Initially it's a `B`. First your loop replaces all `B` characters with `W`. Later it replaces all `W` characters with `6`. Still later it replaces all `6` characters with `H`, which is the character we see in the final position of your output.

Try replacing each character in order, like this:

```
var transformedKey = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (char original in KeyFromClient)
    transformedKey.Append(securityDictionary[original]);
Console.WriteLine(transformedKey.ToString());
```

Matt Burland's answer has a nice one-liner for doing this if you prefer Linq.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are apply replace to a partially encoded string resulting in already encoded characters getting encoded a second (or third, or forth) time.

A simple one line fix:

```
var output = new string(KeyFromClient.Select(c => securityDictionary[c]).ToArray());
```

[Note: it might be worth testing that the key exists in the dictionary if you suspect it is possible that your input string might possibly have values not included in your dictonary]

This loops through your original string and for each character looks up the corresponding entry in your dictionary and builds a new string from it.

It would be more efficient to loop through the string rather than the dictionary anyway.

For your example, with a dictionay with `n` entries and a string of length `m`, you are going to be `O(nm)` because for all `n` entries in the dictionary you need to search all `m` characters of your string to do replacement. By looping on the string, you loop only `m` times and since a dictionary lookup is `O(1)` you are overall `O(m)`.

Comment: Thanks, Matt Burland. Your answer is really simple. +1 for that.